# Count number of items in an array with a specific property value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a Person() class:

```
class Person : NSObject {

    var firstName : String
    var lastName : String
    var imageFor : UIImage?
    var isManager : Bool?

    init (firstName : String, lastName: String, isManager : Bool) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.isManager = isManager
    }
}
```

I have an array of Person()

```
var peopleArray = [Person]()
```

I want to count the number of people in the array who have

```
 isManager: true
```

I feel this is out there, but I can;t find it, or find the search parameters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `filter` method:

```
let managersCount = peopleArray.filter { (person : Person) -> Bool in
    return person.isManager!
}.count
```

or even simpler:

```
let moreCount = peopleArray.filter{ $0.isManager! }.count
```

Comment: Worked great. Much obliged!

Comment: Although this solution works fine, it must be said that it is inefficient if compared `reduce` (see my answer), because it creates a new array - but __if the filtered array itself is needed__ and not its `count` property only, __then this is the right solution__.

Comment: @Antonio Actually, the filtered array came in super handy, too, but both of these methods are super helpful to understand, and you guys explained them better than the documentation and much more efficiently. :)

Answer (score 17):

You can use `reduce` as follows:

```
let count = peopleArray.reduce(0, combine: { (count: Int, instance: Person) -> Int in
    return count + (instance.isManager! ? 1 : 0) }
)
```

or a more compact version:

```
let count = peopleArray.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.isManager! ? 1 : 0) }
```

`reduce` applies the closure (2nd parameter) to each element of the array, passing the value obtained for the previous element (or the initial value, which is the `0` value passed as its first parameter) and the current array element. In the closure you return `count` plus zero or one, depending on whether the isManager property is `true` or not.

More info about `reduce` and `filter` in the [standard library reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH5-SW46)

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't encountered reduce and filter before, I appreciate it.

Comment: Or `peopleArray.reduce(0) { $0 + Int($1.isManager!) }`

Answer (score 10):

⚠️ `count(where:)` was removed from Swift 5 in Xcode 10.2 beta 4.

---

With Swift 5 and Xcode 10.2 beta 3, you can use `Array`'s [`count(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126943-count) method if you want to count the number of elements in an array that match a given predicate. `count(where:)` has the following declaration:

```
func count(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Int
```

> Returns the number of elements in the sequence that satisfy the given predicate.

The following Playground sample code shows how to use `count(where:)`:

```swift
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let isManager: Bool
}

let array = [
    Person(name: "Jane", isManager: true),
    Person(name: "Bob", isManager: false),
    Person(name: "Joe", isManager: true),
    Person(name: "Jill", isManager: true),
    Person(name: "Ted", isManager: false)
]

let managerCount = array.count(where: { (person: Person) -> Bool in
    return person.isManager
})
// let managerCount = array.count { $0.isManager } // also works
        
print(managerCount) // prints: 3
```

Comment: Very good summary of new method (voted), anyway, you can demonstrate this on just simple struct instead of class. Also I would remove `== true` from `person.isManager == true`

Comment: count(where:) was removed from Swift 5 in Xcode 10.2 beta 4 and it never returned it seems.