# How to count occurrences of an element in a Swift / array?

Tags: arrays, swift

How to count a number of time in array there are "Yes" ? In swift

```
["julien: Yes","elie: Yes", "Mark: No", "Jean: Yes"]
```

For exemple here there are 3 times 
Thanks ;)

Comment: What did you try and what went wrong ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? However, I do not think that this is some smart data structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count occurrences of an element in a Swift array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545518/how-to-count-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-swift-array)

Comment: This can be done very simple with enumeration. Or do you want to do this in some smart functional-style way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count number of items in an array with a specific property value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398608/count-number-of-items-in-an-array-with-a-specific-property-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

let array = ["julien: Yes","elie: Yes", "Mark: No", "Jean: Yes"]
let results = array.map({ $0.lowercaseString.containsString("yes") })
let count = results.filter({ $0 == true }).count
count // 3
```

You can also make it a one liner:

```
let count = array.filter({ $0.lowercaseString.containsString("yes") }).count
```

---

**Note:** I also added a check for case sensitivity just incase the data source was inconsistent

Answer (score 2):

```
let a = ["julien: Yes","elie: Yes", "Mark: No", "Jean: Yes"]
let filtered = a.filter { (str) -> Bool in
    return str.containsString("Yes")
}
print(filtered.count)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let array = ["julien: Yes","elie: Yes", "Mark: No", "Jean: Yes"]
let count = array.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.containsString("Yes") ? 1 : 0) }
count // 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSPredicate to get required output like below

```
var arrayTemp = NSMutableArray(objects: "julien: Yes","elie: YES", "elie: NO", "Jean: Yes")
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self contains[cd] %@", "Yes")
arrayTemp.filterUsingPredicate(predicate)
print("COUNT===\(arrayTemp.count)")// 3
```